# What optics system can create an image both smaller and further away from the system than the source object?

Tags: optics

My system comprises of: a light source, a set of lenses, a projected image of the light source.
I want the projected image to be both further away from the lenses and smaller than the source. Which is in contradiction with the optic law that :
source size / source to lens distance= image size/ image to lens distance.

Do you know optical tools that could help me ?

Comment: Holographic projection...

Comment: thanks but overkill in my case, I just need to project a narrow cone of light for microscope epi- illumination

Comment: You asked for optical tools - no budget limit, lacked the detail of working with microscope ...

Comment: Probably www.optenso.com or www.zemax.com can help you. I don't know those programs, though, this is just a guess.

Comment: Not a problem: just generate an intermediate image plane and relay that to your final location.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I tried creating a smaller image with a diverging lens and then relay that with a converging lens. However the  intermediate image will be closer to the converging lens than the source and therefore the final image size doesnt change much

Comment: Hmm..  if it's required to be further away from every single lens in the system, yeah probably can't do.